# Keeping the correct style classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my drag and drop game there is a grid that is populated with words that are hidden from the user. The aim of the game is to spell these words with the aid of a sound and a picture. The user spells a word by dragging and dropping the relevant letters onto the grid. If the letter is correct it will glow green with the class "wordglow3". If it is wrong it will glow red with "wordglow". At the moment I am having a problem because if I drop the correct letter on a word it glows red when it should glow green. It is weird because everything else works like it should after this happens, but I cannot find the source of the problem. Can anyone help?

Here is the script that applies the classes accordingly...

```
 drop: function(event, ui) {
        that = $('.spellword')[guesses[word].length];
        word = $(that).data('word');
        guesses[word].push($(ui.draggable).attr('data-letter'));

        if ($(that).text() == $(ui.draggable).text().trim()) {
            $(that).addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');
            $(".minibutton").hide();
            $('.next').hide();
        } else {
            $(that).addClass('wordglow');
            $('.drag').css("color", "white");
            $(".minibutton").hide();
            $('.next').hide();
        }
```

Fiddle to help - http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/57/

Comment: Maybe the classes "stack", so try removing the other class first: `$(that).removeClass("wordglow").addClass('wordglow3').css('color', 'white');`

Comment: Thanks but no change @Shadow Wizard

Comment: logging $(that).text() returns a blank string:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition seems to be wrong. `$(that).text` is always the empty string.

In the JSFiddle, if you replace it by `$(that).data("letter")`, everything (glow-color related) seems to work.

Comment: Thanks that works. Any idea how I would make the letter dropped display in the box so that the user can see what they have spelt (wrong or right)? @TonioElGringo

Comment: @sMilbz I don't know, maybe something like `$(that).html($(ui.draggable).text().trim())` , and a bit of css to make it looks good.

Comment: That works for correct answers. Any idea for incorrect? @TonioElGringo

Comment: @sMilbz You can do the same. If it is not showing, maybe the css is not right, try `$(that).css('color','white')`. Have fun.